# Tree regression matlab - Node details

Tags: matlab, tree, regression

I am trying to get the list of observations at each leaf of the tree. My whole objective is to obtain the observations at each leaf and to fit a linear model on it. I've been doing manually which is time consuming. Anybody any ideas to get the observation from each leaf?

Comment: How is the data stored and in what format?

Comment: @EJG89 The data used for tree regression is from 1000*16 matrix (0,1). So each leaf has certain number of observations which I wanted to be saved in a matrix or any format so that I can use them to build a regression model.

Answer (score 0):

By observations at each leaf, do you mean the means at each node? Or number of observations...? If it is the mean at each node, click on your tree in the workspace and find NodeMean. That is a list of the mean for each node.

Comment: No, I need all the n observations that are present in each node